# What is the best way to resolve merge conflicts in .swm files?

Tags: git, code-documentation, swimm

When trying to rebase my feature branch on the base branch (dev), I got merge conflicts on `swm` and generated `md` files:

[image: github conflict]

The conflicts themselves are hard to understand on their own, and include many of file blob changes in the `.swm` file:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
            "fileBlob": "107f49a145f675f6b811b13b5a35b1dbfb018f83",
=======
            "fileBlob": "ff2f2a6517bb9c5b86e6ff4d805f8b367a2c5dfc",
>>>>>>> 191d4efc6 (docs(swimm): update document Table API KnevxspVMVO1XfF6UxPS)
```

and this at the end:

[image: swimm merge conflict]

How should I merge these conflicts? Which changes should I pick, and/or how can I test them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for Swimm. These are rare, but unfortunately they do happen.

The best strategy that we've found is to accept the *newest* version, then verify it again. If it's just a case of code moving around, the auto sync algorithm might be able to take it from there. If not, you'll just need to edit the doc and possibly reselect some snippets.

In the *very* near future, we're releasing our `swmd` format, which moves all of the JSON and code waypoints and things completely behind the scenes, with the docs being saved in regular Markdown. So, if you encounter a conflict in the future, it'll be just like merging a regular README file.

If things don't resolve or you can't edit the document properly due to something, reach out to support and they'll get it corrected.

Comment: Thanks! Just for future reference, since our workflow is rebasing, I ran `git checkout --ours .swm` (in merge workflows it'll be `git checkout --theirs .swm`)